# what does "::functionName()" imply in c++?

Tags: c++

I came across a piece of code which looks like this:

```
::GetSystemDirectory(buffer, MAX_PATH);
```

I've never seen a function call preceded by an empty `::`. I've always seen them being used with namespaces.

Can someone please explain me what does an empty `::` mean ?

Comment: Global namespace usually.

Comment: @Rapptz What if I just call the function without it ? Will it only restrict it to current namespace ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the scope resolution operator. With nothing in front of it, it indicates global scope.

So for instance, suppose you have a class that defines its own `GetSystemDirectory` method. Within the code of a method of that class, to call the global one, you'd need the `::` in front of it, otherwise by default you'd get the one specific to the class. (And similarly for namespaces.)

Comment: I believe, it would make most sense to call the system functions with the `::` then ?

Comment: @brainydexter: I haven't done enough C++ in the last 15 years to really have an opinion on that. *Sounds* reasonable. :-)